# Save query result in var

Tags: php, image

So i got this code:

```
<?php
include('dbconnect.php');
if(isset($_POST['remover']))
{
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$result = mysql_query("select imagem from sitio WHERE id_sitio='".$nome."'");
$query=mysql_query("DELETE FROM sitio WHERE id_sitio='".$nome."'") or die (mysql_error());
if($query === true)
  {
    $sucesso = '<span  class="yes">Sitio removido com sucesso!</span>';
    echo $sucesso;
    echo $result;
  }
  else
    {
        $erro = '<span class="error">Ocorreu um erro!</span>';
        echo $retorno;
    }
}
?>
```

I want this to select the image name from the database. The script delete the data from the db, so the query is ok. But the $result dont return the name of the image. Its returns Resource id#10. I want to do this to then do a unlink of the image. I just used echo to see if it was correct, and the result is not what is on the database..

Can someone help me?

Comment: _"Its returns Resource id#10."_ - if you don't know why, then please work through some basic tutorials that explain how to fetch data from MySQL result sets.

Comment: so how do i store in a $var the result of the query?

so then i can do like : unlink('/folder/$query');

Comment: @CBroe I disagree.  I believe reading the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/set.mysqlinfo.php) is better.  Also, most of the tutorials out there use the deprecated mysql_ functions.

Comment: using mysql_num_rows(result); retunrs the value "array". using mysql_fetch_object($result); returns an error: Class could not be converted to string.~

Answer (score 1):

You have not collected the results of your first query. mysql_query() when run with a select query generates a resultset, a bit like a temporary table with only the fields you specifiy in the query.
This can contain one row, as yours does, or many rows.
Once mysql_query() has run successfully you must then get the data from the resultset one row at a time using either

```
mysql_fetch_object()
mysql_fetch_array()
mysql_fetch_assoc()
mysql_fetch_row()
```

each delivers the row in a slightly different format i.e. an array or an object or just a single field.

Check out the manual here [PHP mysql functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php)

Try this code for example:

```
<?php
    include('dbconnect.php');
    if(isset($_POST['remover'])) {
        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $result = mysql_query("select imagem from sitio WHERE id_sitio='".$nome."'");
        // collect the data from the previous query
        $sitio = mysql_fetch_object($result);

        $query=mysql_query("DELETE FROM sitio WHERE id_sitio='".$nome."'") or die (mysql_error());
        if($query === true) {
            echo '<span  class="yes">Sitio removido com sucesso!</span>';
            echo $sitio->imagem;
        }  else  {
            echo '<span class="error">Ocorreu um erro!</span>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Yes that showed the image name! I replaced echo with unlink("/images_sitios/$imageurl->imagem"); and it says: unlink(/images_sitios/1372330843.jpg, No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\SITE\backoffice\remover_sitio.php on line 64

Comment: Remove the leading slash.  unlink('images_sitios/1372330843.jpg')

Comment: i dont have 15 reputation :/